# Writing to xls file in Python

Tags: python

I am having trouble writing to an existing XLS file in python. Here is what I have so far:

```
import_data = xlrd.open_workbook('Example.xls', on_demand=True)
```

Edit data, create work book, save new data to worksheet and then...

```
wb.save('Example.xls')
```

Error:

```
Invalid argument: 'Example.xls'
```

If I change the file name in the save method, it works exactly as intended. Example:

```
wb.save('Example2.xls')
```

So it would appear that I am having an issue writing to a file that already exists. I searched for a way to 'close' Example.xls but from what I read it sounds like that isn't necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `release_resources()` to release document. It's required if `on_demand=True` parameter is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wb.release_resources()
# Edit your data.
wb.save('Example.xls')
```

Comment: Yep! Got it! Closed since it was a duplicate.